# Is it possible to access the matrix parameters (name-value pair separated by semicolon) in ColdFusion?

Tags: url, coldfusion, uri, cfml

I'm new to [matrix parameter](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html) and I know CF10 can access them through their new RESTful API support.

However, is there a way to access these parameters without using RESTful API support?

E.g. `http://moremaps.com/map/color.cfm;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000`

Comment: You can do `color.cfm;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000` then get the param string with `ListRest(getPageContext().getRequest().getRequestUri(),';')`

Comment: @PeterBoughton Thank you, would you please post it as an answer? thanks

Comment: Any idea why we don't have a Matrix scope for this? hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
color.cfm;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000
```

Then get the param string with:

```
ListRest(getPageContext().getRequest().getRequestUri(),';')
```

This worked back in CFMX - it's not specific to CF10 or part of the RESTful API, and is available due to the servlet container (Tomcat/Jrun/etc) following the servlet spec with the ability to get the original URL.

<sub>(And you can of course use URL rewriting to hide the .cfm from the user.)</sub>

---

There isn't a matrix scope because CF hasn't implemented it fully - it is done as part of REST webservices, (where it's as an argument with the appropriate `RestArgSource` attribute). Only the CF team can say why they designed it that way.

However, you can easily create your own scope/struct like so:

```
var MatrixString = ListRest(getPageContext().getRequest().getRequestUri(),';');
var Matrix = {};

for ( var CurParam in ListToArray(MatrixString,';') )
    Matrix[ UrlDecode( ListFirst(CurParam,'=') ) ] = UrlDecode( ListRest(CurParam,'=') );
```

<sub>(Obviously, remove the var scoping if not using inside a function.)</sub>

That works both directly and via IIS, and should work fine on other servers too, even where path_info may have been modified.

---

**Update:** This answer is incomplete/inaccurate.

Reading up further on matrix params, they can actually appear at any point in the request_uri (the entire part after the host_name, before the query_string) - that is, both script_name and path_info can contain parameters, without affecting their final value.

To clarify this, both these URLs:

```
htp://domain.com/a/b.cfm/c/d
http://domain.com/a;alpha=1/b.cfm;beta=2/c;gamma=3/d;delta=4
```

Result in these CGI vars:

```
script_name = /a/b.cfm
path_info = /c/d
```

<sub>(Except in IIS, where path_info is incorrectly implemented.)</sub>

Obviously extracting and acting upon these properties is more complex than the code above - I'll update this answer again once I've made sure I understand them more fully.

In the meantime, here's a couple of potential options - the first returns a struct of params if a path element has one, the second returns an array containing every path element - whether either of these are suitable will depend on how the matrix params are to be used:

```
<cffunction name="getMatrixStruct" returntype="Struct" output=false
    hint="Returns struct with item for each path element with params"
    >
    <cfargument name="RequestUri" type="String" required hint="The non-host and non-querystring part of a URL." />
    <cfscript>
        var Result = {};

        for ( var CurSegment in ListToArray(RequestUri,'/') )
        {
            var SegName = UrlDecode( ListFirst(CurSegment,';') );

            for ( var CurParam in ListToArray(ListRest(CurSegment,';')) )
                Result[SegName][UrlDecode( ListFirst(CurParam,'=') ) ] = UrlDecode( ListRest(CurParam,'=') );

        }

        return Result;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>


<cffunction name="getMatrixArray" returntype="Array" output=false
    hint="Returns array of structs for all path element, with any parameters included."
    >
    <cfargument name="RequestUri" type="String" required hint="The non-host and non-querystring part of a URL." />
    <cfscript>
        var Result = [];
        var Pos = 0;

        for ( var CurSegment in ListToArray(RequestUri,'/') )
        {
            Result[++Pos] = { 'Name' = UrlDecode( ListFirst(CurSegment,';') ) };

            for ( var CurParam in ListToArray(ListRest(CurSegment,';')) )
                Result[Pos][UrlDecode( ListFirst(CurParam,'=') ) ] = UrlDecode( ListRest(CurParam,'=') );

        }

        return Result;
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it via `cgi.path_info`. For example:

```
 http://localhost/myApp/index.cfm;this=that;pet=cat
```

Becomes

```
cgi.PATH_INFO=/MyApp/index.cfm;this=that;pet=cat
```

Then you can

```
struct function getMatrix() output="false"  {

   var arURLData = ListToArray(cgi.path_Info, ";");

   var stData = {};

   if (arrayLen(arData) <= 1) {
      return stData;
   }

   for(var i = 2; i <= ArrayLen(arData); i++) {

     // setVariable("stData.#listfirst(arURLData[i], "=")#", listlast(arURLData[i]);
     stData[listfirst(arURLData[i], "=")] = getToken(arURLData[i], 2, "=");
   }

   return stData;
}
```

You will probably want to add some code to protect against URL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately `CGI.PATH_INFO` is broken in CF10 http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1157829

Comment: Are any cgi variables available?

Comment: It is available, but it's `[empty string]`.  I guess it's because I'm using IIS 7.5, see forum.

Comment: Curious why you would use setVariable(). in 10+ years as a CF developer, I have never used that function.

Comment: It is a bad habit. Something like `stData[listfirst(...` would work too

Comment: Did you mean `listlast(arURLData[i], "=")`? Or better yet `getToken(text, 2, '=')`, in case the value is blank.